# What gives the hover and click styles in w8 xaml?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

When using a listitem in a w8 app, how can I determine what gives the hover and click styles?

My listview looks like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="itemsListView"
          TabIndex="1"
          Visibility="Visible"
          Padding="10,0,0,0" Foreground="Black"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes.Nodes}"
          behaviors:ListViewItemClickedToAction.Action="{Binding SelectNodeAction}"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True" FontFamily="Global User Interface"
          >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

When I hover using the mouse I get white letters and an almost white background.

I have tried reusing parts of the adventureworks shopper app, so there are styles from there copied. However, I can't understand what is applied to the ListView items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe already new this but if you check this [screenshot](http://smutsmuts.com/Screenshots/ScreenshotOne.png) you can see how you easily in VS2012 can create a copy of a built in style. When you press the "Edit a copy ..." a dialog will appear where you can choose where in the Project you want the style to be placed.

You can inherit styles. The inheritence of styles work in the following way:

```
<Style x:Name="BasicStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
</Style>

<Style x:Name="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource BasicStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
</Style>
```

You can do inheritence in several steps so Another button style can inherit the "ButtonStyle".
You can thus make a style that only contains the Template property if you want to seperate it or reuse the behaviour and look of your style. But you cannot split the Visual State Manager into several styles since if you inherit a style which sets the template property and then if you want to change the Hover state of that style you need to make a copy of the whole template and only change that part in the code.

I Think this would be a nice improvement by MS if you could make a style which only contains the pressed state and then Another style which only contains the hover effect and so on.

I hope this answers your questions :) I would love to answer more questions regarding XAML if you have any!